# Image read in Java

Tags: java, image, file, byte

I am trying to read a image with the following code, I wasn't able to figure it out why its happening. If there is anything I done wrong in the following code, please tell me.

```
System.out.println("Image Bytes ::"+imageBytes);

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);

System.out.println("Buff Image :: "+img);
```

and the Output is as follows:

```
Image Bytes ::[B@4554617c
Buff Image :: null
```

Comment: The javadoc says: *If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.* So, your byte array doesn't contain an image that Java can decode. Where do these bytes come from?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Source of your imageByte is unknown, it's would be hard to say what went wrong. But if your are creating that byteSource, then probably the below code will help you, because **From the Javadocs for ImageIO.read()**

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with
>   an  ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently
>   registered. The File is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. If no
>   registered  ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting
>   stream, null is returned.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Created by ankur on 13/7/15.
 * The Following program will read an image file.
 * convert it into byte array, and then reuse the
 * converted byte array, and convert it back to new BufferedImage
 *
 */
public class ImageToBuf {

    public  static  void main(String... strings) throws IOException {
        byte[] imageInByte;
        //read the image
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/ankur/Pictures/BlpRb.png"));
        //convert BufferedImage to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", byteOutS);
        byteOutS.flush();
        imageInByte = byteOutS.toByteArray();
        byteOutS.close();

        //convert byte array back to BufferedImage
        InputStream readedImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
        BufferedImage bfImage = ImageIO.read(readedImage);
        System.out.println(bfImage);
    }
}
```

OutPut(on my amchine):

```
BufferedImage@21b8d17c: type = 13 IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@6433a2 transparency = 1 transIndex   = -1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 4959 height = 3505 #numDataElements 1 dataOff[0] = 0
```